# Cannot convert from java.lang.Class<T> to java.lang.Class<T>

Tags: java, generics, compiler-errors

I'm having this problem. Shouldn't the constructor have the same type parameters as the class?

```
public class MyBuilder<T> {

private final Class<T> clss;

/**
 *
 * @param clss
 */
public <T> MyBuilder(final Class<T> clss) {
    this.clss = (Class<T>) clss; // compiler error here
}


Type mismatch: cannot convert from java.lang.Class<T> to java.lang.Class<T>
```

If I remove the `<T>` for the ctor it compiles, but I cannot do :

```
MyBuilder<Foo> myBuilder = new MyBuilder<Foo>();   // compiler error here
```

The error is The constructor `MyBuilder<Foo>()` is undefined.

Comment: Why is the <T> in the Constructor signature?

Comment: Because this "T" is not that "T". T is just a "place holder" for some type. The T in private final Class<T> clss; is unrelated to the T in the constructor parameter.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen <T> in the Constructor signature is valid. How is ArrayList<T> defined?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Remove the type parameter from the constructor, as well as the cast:

```
public MyBuilder(final Class<T> clss) {
   this.clss = clss;
}
```

The type parameters of a class, `T` in this case, are implicitly declared for any instance members, including constructors.  By explicitly declaring `T` for the constructor you were actually masking the `T` declared by the class, causing that confusing error.

Comment: Right, well you can't instantiate using a default constructor because you haven't defined one to set the final field). Also the class is abstract anyway.

Answer (score 5):

Because this "T" is not that "T". T is just a "place holder" for some type. The T in

```
private final Class<T> clss;
```

is unrelated to the T in the constructor parameter.